# Show comma in CSV without using the comma character

Tags: c#, csv, character-replacement

I have a **log in CSV format** we write out for a certain logging operation. However, one of the fields allows **user input** and I need to make sure that *if they enter a comma in the field that we parse it out and replace it with something* that, say, Excel will be able to read and show a comma in its place (so the csv reader will not think it is the end of a column).

Currently I replace the comma with `&#44;` but this is **shows as a literal** string in Excel.

Is there a standard way to display a comma in a CSV file without using the actual comma character? Even a solution that only works with excel will work, since most of our customers will be using Excel to view this file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best way to handle embedded commas is to properly quote the CSV file:

- Columns that contain a comma should be quoted
- Quoted columns that contain a quote should have the quote escaped

Example:

> Joe Smith, "Joe Smith, Jr.", "Joe ""The Man"" Smith, Jr."

I wrote an extension method that helps solve this:

```
static public string CsvQuote(this string text)
{
    if (text == null) return string.Empty;

    bool containsQuote = false;
    bool containsComma = false;
    int len = text.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len && (containsComma == false || containsQuote == false); i++)
    {
        char ch = text[i];
        if (ch == '"')
        {
            containsQuote = true;
        }
        else if (ch == ',' || char.IsControl(ch))
        {
            containsComma = true;
        }
    }

    bool mustQuote = containsComma || containsQuote;

    if (containsQuote)
    {
        text = text.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
    }

    // Quote the cell and replace embedded quotes with double-quote or just return as is
    return mustQuote ? "\"" + text + "\"" : text;
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
logger.Write(myString.CsvQuote());

var csv = string.Join(",", listOfStrings.Select(CsvQuote))
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that CSV parsers were smart enough to escape entire fields as strings like that

Comment: Not all do, especially Excel

Comment: @MareInfinitus: Excel understands the format I described.  I do that all the time with huge data sets.  Almost any software that's maintained and claims to handle CSV files will understand this quoting.

Comment: Quoting is usally a good way to do such things. Depending on the parser you use.

Comment: I made one change to this: `else if (ch == ',' || char.IsControl(ch))` this will make sure strings with CRLFs get quoted too

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: Thanks. I made a similar change in my own codebase some time ago. Integrated your change into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Including your string inside of quotation marks will let you use commas.

`"please sir,", can I, have some more?`

Answer (score 0):

CSV is also "character separated values", not only comma.

You can use any character as a separator, but the `tab` or `\t` is widely used for this,
as it typically not used in user input.

The RFC for CSV is [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)

It suggests to use data fields and field separators. Here is the original text,
please note the special part of Microsoft Excel in (5)

> ```
> 5.  Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
>    some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
>    at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
>    double quotes may not appear inside the fields.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","bbb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
>
> 6.  Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
>    should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b CRLF
>    bb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
>
> 7.  If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>    appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>    another double quote.  For example:
>
>    "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
> ```

Please also note that Excel recognizes Tab out of the Box

Comment: Like any special character, it *can* show up in data to be logged, if not now perhaps years down the road after someone updates the code.  I suggest proper quoting.

Comment: There will always be a bad programmer breaking your architecture and design in years. There is no silver bullet.

Comment: "You can always get t-boned by a drunk driver" doesn't mean it's a bad idea to wear your seat belt.  Practicing sound architecture and design reduces opportunities for less-skilled developers to break things.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a quotes around the entire field.  Most CSV parsers will understand that the comma is part of the data and not the end of the field.

Or use a different separator.  This will require you use the text import wizard in Excel instead of just being able to open the file directly.  I typically use`~` or `|`.

Comment: That worked great for us years ago until someone named his company along the lines of Store || (yes he used pipe characters).  Special characters create special problems.  I strongly suggest the use of proper quoting.